# How to drag multiple targets on a map?

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I wanted to implement a function that users can drag the marker (which is defined as *MapQuickItem*) on the map and automatically change its path (which is defined as *MapPolyline*). Currently I can only drag the marker but don't know how to change its path.

[image]

[image]

If I want to define a *DropArea* under the *Map* and call the *MapPolyline.removeCoordinate()* function to change the path, how to visit the index in the *delegate*? And I'm not sure if this idea will work.

Here is the code:

```
    Map {
        id: map
        anchors.fill: parent
        plugin: mapPlugin
        zoomLevel: 14
        activeMapType: supportedMapTypes[7]

        /* maker */
        MouseArea {
            anchors.fill: parent
            onClicked: {
                var crd = map.toCoordinate(Qt.point(mouseX, mouseY))
                console.log(crd)
                markerModel.append({ "latitude": crd.latitude, "longitude": crd.longitude})
                line.addCoordinate(crd)
            }
        }

        MapItemGroup {
            MapPolyline {
                id: line
                line.width: 3
                line.color: "#515151"
            }

            MapItemView {
                add: Transition {}

                remove: Transition {}

                model: ListModel {
                    id: markerModel
                }

                delegate:
                    MapQuickItem {
                        id: marker
                        coordinate: QtPositioning.coordinate(latitude, longitude)
                        anchorPoint: Qt.point(markerImage.width * 0.5, markerImage.height * 0.5)

                        sourceItem: Image {
                            id: markerImage
                            z: 5
                            width: 30
                            height: 30
                            source: index <= 0 ? "Images/starting point.svg" : "Images/point black.svg"
                            MouseArea {
                                anchors.fill: parent

                                onClicked: {
                                    line.removeCoordinate(index);
                                    markerModel.remove(index);
                                }

                                drag.target: marker
                            }
                        }
                    }
                /* maker */
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried several methods to solve the problem.

1. This method is not feasible cos the event (*drag.onActiveChanged*) is triggered only at the moment that the drag event happens.

```
drag.onActiveChanged: {
    if(mouseArea.drag.active) { 
            line.replaceCoordinate(index, marker.coordinate); 
    }   
}
```

2. I tried to define a *DropArea* under the *Map* and called the *drag.ondragStarted()* function to trigger the event, but I didn't figure out how to visit the index in the delegate, then I gave up.
3. It worked! When I dragged the marker on the map, the path automatically changed! The event (*onPositionChanged*) is triggered everytime the coordinate of marker changes.

```
onPositionChanged: {
    line.replaceCoordinate(index, marker.coordinate);
}
```

Thank myself :-)